# JQuery table filter with text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering, html-table

Need to filter a table from outside of the table, with a text search. For example, if i write down a word in input element, i want to get all rows of the table which content that word.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your "head" section of the page:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();

            $("#searchTable tr td").each(function (i) {
                var content = $(this).text();
                if (content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1) {
                    $(this).parent().hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And lets suppose your html looks like:

```
   <div>
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" />
        <table id="searchTable">
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Latest</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mest</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Best</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>chest</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Waste</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Test</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several javascript libraries for this usecase, found

- [List.js](http://listjs.com/)

to work quite well. I thought the commonly used [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin for jquery had some sort of extension but I could no longer find it.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, other frontend table sorting/searching libs I didn't test on projects:

- [Dynatable](http://www.dynatable.com)

  - this one seems to be more feature-rich than List.js
- [Sortable](http://github.hubspot.com/sortable/docs/welcome/)

  - does sorting only

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would help you.

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput" />
<table id="searchTable">
<td>test</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>test2</td>
<td>test</td>
<td>test3</td>
<td>test</td>
</table>

<script>
$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
var val = $(this).val();

$("#searchTable td").each(function(i) {
    var content = $(this).html();
    if(content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        $(this).show();
    }
});
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pCBe4/

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This will work better:

```
$("#txtFilter").keyup(function () {
    var val = $(this).val().toLocaleLowerCase();
    $("tr", table).each(function (i) {
        var content = '';
        $(this).find('td').each(function (j) {
            content += '' + $(this).text().trim();
        });

        if (content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1) {
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```